# Conditional UNION in LINQ (or is there a better way than UNIONs)?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following object model

```
public class CityData
{
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int IncidentsReported { get; set; }
}
```

I have a web service method (that I cannot alter the code for) that gives me data for all the cities my company's offices are in.

```
var data = GetCitiesData();
```

The above method returns only cities with incidents > 0. BUT I want all cities regardless of incident counts. I tried to solve my problem using the [LINQ Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407(v=vs.100).aspx) Method.

```
var data = GetCitiesData()
                        .Union(
                    new[]
                    {
                        // Add all cities with 0 incidents
                        new CityData() {  CityName = "Kansas City", IncidentsReported = 0},
                        new CityData() {  CityName = "St Louis", IncidentsReported = 0},
                        new CityData() {  CityName = "New York", IncidentsReported = 0},
                    },
                     new CityComparer()
                );
```

Here is my implementation of CityComparer

```
public class CityComparer : IEqualityComparer<CityData>
{
    public bool Equals(CityData x, CityData y)
    {
        return x.CityName == y.CityName;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CityData obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

but still I am getting what can be the result of [LINQ Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx) not [LINQ Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407(v=vs.100).aspx)

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: @Tuco no. But I have the list of cities where we have offices.

Comment: how you define the `GetHashCode`?

Comment: I'm guessing your implementation of `GetHashCode` is wrong.  Can you post it too?

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca return obj.GetHashCode()

Comment: If `GetHashCode` returns different values `Equals` is never called

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca This could be the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define [GetHashCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132155(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this:

```
public int GetHashCode(CityData x)
{
    return x.CityName.GetHashCode();
}
```

Before Union calls [Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132154(v=vs.110).aspx) method it checks hash codes of objects, and if they are different, Equals method won't call.

From MSDN:

> Implementations are required to ensure that if the Equals method
>   returns true for two objects x and y, then the value returned by the
>   GetHashCode method for x must equal the value returned for y.

Comment: That is what I have. Sorry it was not listed earlier. I just listed it.

Comment: @fahadash yes, my mistake, fixed

Comment: Sweet, solved my problem. Don't know which of the answers to Accept :)

Comment: @fahadash added more explanation and links to msdn

Answer (score 5):

You need to match `GetHashCode` to `Equals` on your comparer:

```
public int GetHashCode(CityData x)
{
    return x.CityName.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Sweet, solved my problem. Don't know which of the answers to Accept :)

Comment: I would love to know a better way than UNIONs though

Comment: @fahadash why don't you just return all the cities regardless of incidents in `GetCitiesData`? I think you should accept @Backs answer, he beat me by some seconds :-)

Comment: GetCitiesData() is a third party web service that I have no access to.

Comment: @fahadash well, if the third party service won't give you the data you need, you should ask for it, not a lot you can do :-)